# Reading csv data into a table in postgresql via INSERT INTO with Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a postgresql table created in python that I need to then populate with data from a csv file. The csv file has 4 columns and a header row. When I use a for loop with `INSERT INTO` it's not working correctly.

It is giving me an error telling me that a certain column doesn't exist, but the column is actually the first ID in the ID column.

I've looked over all the similar issues reported on other questions and can't seem to find something that works.

The table looks like this (with more lines):

| ID | Gender | Weight | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | F | 121 | 20 |
| B | M | 156 | 31 |
| C | F | 110 | 18 |

The code I am running is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')

for x in df.index:
    cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO iddata (ID, Gender, Weight, Age)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %d, %d)""" % (df.loc[x]['ID'],
                                  df.loc[x]['Gender'],
                                  df.loc[x]['Weight'],
                                  df.loc[x]['Age']))
    conn.commit
```

The error I'm getting says

```
UndefinedColumn: column "a" does not exist
LINE 3:     VALUES (A, F, 121, 20)
                    ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `""" %` with `""",`.

Also add `()` after the `.commit()`.

The fixed loop code becomes:

```py
for x in df.index:
    cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO iddata (ID, Gender, Weight, Age)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %d, %d)""", (df.loc[x]['ID'],
                                 df.loc[x]['Gender'],
                                 df.loc[x]['Weight'],
                                 df.loc[x]['Age']))
    conn.commit()
```

The reason why you need a comma `,` is to pass the data (4-element tuple) as the 2nd argument of *cursor.execute*. By doing so, *cursor.execute* will take care of correct quoting and escaping. This matters for string values: proper escaping will make sure that strings containing any characters (including `'`, `"` and `\`) will be sent intact to the database.

Comment: Thank you! This allowed the code to run without the undefined column error, however, it is now giving me a ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'nump.int64' error

Comment: You may want to use `int(df.loc[x]['Weight'])` and likewise for Age. However, this should be asked as a separate question on StackOverflow.